# Popup Window from Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain, silverlight-5.0

I have strange problem with SL5 Pop-up.

My SL5 app works and fetch data from WCF service located on other domain. On one button click,  some service method is called and returns a path of file. On return from service, result is used to open popup window. Since it is not user instantiated following code is used to achieve this

```
new Repository().SaveExporttoExcelData(builder.ToString(), (result) =>
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        var options = new System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPopupWindowOptions();
                        options.Left = 0; options.Top = 0; options.Width = 80; options.Height = 60;

                        string servicePath=  path;
                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            string excelPath = servicePath.Replace("\\","/") +"/"+ result.ToString();
                            System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval(string.Format("window.open('{0}','{1}','{2}')", excelPath, "new", options.ToString()));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageDialog.Show("Error in downloading file. Please try again.");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

This works fine if I am running SL5 app from VS and service pointed to prod service environment. But the same SL does not work when I host xap on prod web. I am on citrix, and the same also work from same network where web is hosted.  I have also closed the proxy connection, before opening the popup.

The url is generated fine, and popup appears for a while and close without downloading the file. but if I copy the URL and open in browser, I am able to download the file. I have checked the popup blocker settings and proxy connection.

Comment: Have you got the proper clientaccesspolicy.xml/crossdomain.xml files setup?

Comment: Yup, I am able to call the services and get the result. Only thing it is not able to open the file from popup but works if one the same url in Browser Window